# Site Contents link in Quick Launch below Edit link (SharePoint 2013)

Tags: 2013, web-template

I'm creating a custom WebTemplate. I added the following NavBars to the template:

```
    <NavBars>
    <NavBar Name="SharePoint Top Navigation Bar" Url="" ID="1002" />
    <NavBar Name="Home" ID="1031" />
    <NavBar Name="Project Documents" Url="Lists/ProjectDocuments" />
    <NavBar Name="Project Tasks" Url="Lists/Tasks/AllItems.aspx" />
    <NavBar Name="Recent" ID="1033" />
    <NavBar Name="Site Contents" ID="1034" />
</NavBars>
```

The resulting site has Site Contents twice.

[image]

Removing the NavBar element for Site Contents results in only one Site Contents link being rendered, however it is the one below the Edit Links button.

Any tips for fixing the location and/or removing the duplicate?

Answer (score 1):

I found an easy solution with no need to change navigation style.

In the page layout HTML file find

`<div class="ms-core-listMenu-verticalBox">`

add a `style="display:none"`.

The second (and further... I had sometime 2 "site contents" links there...) and ONLY that one will disappear, keeping save the other links in the quick launch menu (I have tested both in on premise and 365).

Answer (score 0):

you have two options:

1. hide "edit links" with js / css
2. Switch from "Managed Navigation" to "Structural Navigation" in ~/_layouts/15/AreaNavigationSettings.aspx

Answer (score 0):

call the following css overwrite:

```
#ctl00_PlaceHolderLeftNavBar_PlaceHolderQuickLaunchBottom_idNavLinkViewAll
{
 visibility:hidden; 
}
```